# Stray start tag script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a tooltip from http://www.wowhead.com/hearthstone/tooltips to work on my site but it doesn't work so I tried the W3C validator for answers and I got the following error:

Error Line 88, Column 84: **Stray start tag script**.
…//static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"**>**var wowhead_tooltips =…

Heres my code of that section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"> </script>

<script> var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks":       true } </script>
```

And it's within the `<html>` and `<head>` tags.

Comment: what doctype are you using?

Comment: Where are these in your document?

Comment: The site doesn't show that error now, and your code doesn't provide enough context to tell what the problem was. We have no idea what came before `<script>`

Comment: Well check this, might help: http://adamsdotter.se/blog/w3c-validator-error-stray-script-start-tag/

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Validator gives that error when you've something outside `</body>`.

Just move your script tags inside `<body>`, or keep them in `<head>`.