# Stray start tag script in validator

Tags: html

While validating a HTML5 page using the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/), I am getting the following error.

> Stray start tag script

Please help me to remove this error

Comment: W3Schools is in no way related to the W3C or the W3C Validator. Unless you can show us your markup, anything we say is just a wild guess but this question will be removed before then.

Answer (score 3):

Can check this out. [Someone had the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958667/stray-start-tag-script)

*Validator gives that error when you've something outside `</body>`.
Just move your script tags inside `<body>`, or keep them in `<head>`.*